# Перебрать всевозможные вариации чисел из нескольких списков (PYTHON)

Tags: python, алгоритм, перебор

У меня есть три списка (их может быть разное количество): 
['6', '2'], ['9', '3', '5'], ['6', '8'] 
Мне требуется перебрать всевозможные комбинации этих списков, т.е.:
696 698 636 638 и т.д.

Пробовал использовать itertools, но не нашел там подходящей функции. 
**Сложность заключается в том, что может быть разное количество списков, и их длина тоже может быть разной.** 
*Использую python*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *Длина элемента в списках всегда = 1, т.е. это всегда одна цифра.
*Списков может быть как 2, так и 8.
*Длина списков от 2 до 4.

Comment: Ну как не нашли https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-itertools-python/funktsija-product-modulja-itertools/

Comment: Я очень сильно сомневался, что в itertools нет подходящей функции, но глаз на эту не пал). Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод product модуля itertools, вот как это может выглядеть:

```
from itertools import product


def func(*args):
   return [''.join(i) for i in product(*args)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(func(['6', '2'], ['9', '3', '5'], ['6', '8']))
```

Вывод: ['696', '698', '636', '638', '656', '658', '296', '298', '236', '238', '256', '258']